# How to remove an android push notification from notification center when the app gets started by its launcher icon?

Tags: android, notifications, push, google-cloud-messaging

I'd like to remove all pending notifications, if the user starts the app via the launcher icon. This is kind of related to this question (iOS) [How to catch all iOS Push Notifications with different user actions including tap on app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290661/how-to-get-all-the-pending-push-notifications-from-ios-notification-center-after) , only that i don't care about any data/info from the notifications.

Is this possible?

(So far i read in the docs, that you can cancel specific notifications. A simple .clearAll() call would be best)

Regards, Richard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) has a `clearAll()` method that you can call

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33735457/7124487 is the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

In your MainActivity:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.cancelAll();
```